# Microsoft.sharepoint.dll for WSS 2.0

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

I have a VS.net project where I need to add a reference to Microsoft.sharepoint.dll
where can I find the dll. I am running my web application on XP Professional box and I cannot install WSS 2.0 on my machine.

I need to programmatically access a sharepoint site which is on WSS 2.0 from aSP.net application.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/pandrew/archive/2008/05/01/getting-started-with-sharepoint-development.aspx) to get started.

One thing that was mentioned pretty early on is that you really should install sharepoint on the local dev machine. I have never tried developing without it (and I fear it is a requirement) as it makes getting the job done so much easier. Furthermore, you can't break the production server. Nevertheless, installing the Sharepoint Developer Kit from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=05E0DD12-8394-402B-8936-A07FE8AFAFFD&displaylang=en) is also pretty mandatory.

In the past, I have just used a VM with win2k3/2k8, sharepoint and the current flavour of Visual Studio and worked in a local virtualised machine. Made it easy to work with, roll back to non-broken states and meant I didn't need to kill my dev machine with Sharepoint etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to decide is are you going to access SharePoint via the object model or the web services

**Object Model - (Microsoft.SharePoint.dll)**

- +. More complete access, there are many
  things you can do via the OM that you
  can't do with the web services
- +. Performance - you will likely get better performance
- -. Less scalability - you can't scale requests over multiple web front ends
- -. Your program must be running on a server that has SharePoint installed

**Web Services**

- +. Can use from any machine that can access your SharePoint site, i.e. no need for Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

If your program is running as an ASP.NET site and you don't want to limit this to running on the same server as SharePoint then WebServices are probably your way forward.

More info...

[SO - Querying list items and using SharePoint web services vs the object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324272/querying-list-items-and-using-sharepoint-web-services-vs-the-object-model)